# Interface with methods to return C# generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm not sure how to accurately explain this topic so forgive any errors in lingo.
In simple terms, I have 4 different entities in my db that store various types of data. I am trying to create an interface, that can be used for the 4 classes in my data project to retrieve the data for each since they are all similar.

I have tried a few versions of the interface, the latest being.

```
 public interface ISqlTradeDataRetriever
{
    Task<T> GetByPrimaryKeysAsync<T>(string symbol, string date);

    Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(string symbol);

    Task<ICollection<T>> GetDataInDateRange<T>(string symbol, KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime> dateRange);       
}
```

These are methods that all of the entities can use so I'm trying to minimize code. The problem lies in the actual class that does the work as I need to return different entity types. This is a bit advanced for my level at the moment.

```
public class SqlCommodityDataRetriever : ISqlTradeDataRetriever
{
    private readonly IBatlGroupWebContext _context;

    public SqlCommodityDataRetriever(IBatlGroupWebContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

   public Task<T> GetByPrimaryKeysAsync<T>(string symbol, string date)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Commodity))
        {
            return _context.Commodities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Symbol == symbol
                                                                 && m.TradeDate == Convert.ToDateTime(date));

        }
        return null;
    }

    public Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(string symbol)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<ICollection<T>> GetDataInDateRange<T>(string symbol, KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime> dateRange)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }      
}
```

For this class I need to return the entity dbSet Commodities or the single Commodity entity and I am not sure how I can return different types as I would use this interface for 3 other classes.

Can this be done or is it not going to save much in the way of code?
The problem, as in the one method above is VS complains that Commodity can't be converted to T.

With the interface defined as `ISqlTradeDataRetriever<T>` and the class as

```
public class SqlCommodityDataRetriever : ISqlTradeDataRetriever<Commodity>
{}
```

There are no errors. Will have to test and see if it works

Comment: "`if (typeof(T) == typeof(Commodity))`"  this type of code allways makes me feel like generics aren´t the right thing here. Generics are ment to be - well - **generic**, which means they work for **any** type, not just a few.

Comment: One note: you can write `GetByPrimaryKeysAsync<T>(string symbol, string date) where T :  Commodity`.

Comment: It would help if you post the code for `IBatlGroupWebContext`. I assume the concrete implementation is an EF context?

Comment: If each implementation only supports a single result type then you should consider moving the generic parameter into the interface i.e. `ISqlTradeDataReceiver<T>`.

Comment: @dinotom I belive you should take a look at this: https://garywoodfine.com/generic-repository-pattern-net-core/

Comment: @SeM... I thought of that but you can't put that in the interface and adding that to the code in the data class produces a constraint error that the method doesn't match the interface

Comment: @Lee that appears to work well, in the class. See the edit above.

Comment: Your interface is generic, that's fine. But your implementation cannot be generic because you need code like `_context.Commodities`. What you are doing is similar to the Repository Pattern.

Comment: He can always abstract out the `Set<T>` method (add it to the interface).